# Converting python bytes into a c struct

Tags: python, c, struct

So I'm optimizing a game playing bot and have run out of optimizations in pure python. Currently, most of the time is spent translating one game state into the next game state for the alpha-beta search. The current thinking is that I could speed this up by writing the state-transition code in C. My problem comes from trying to convert the python State into a struct that C can operate on and back again.

Currently, states are uniquely represented by a byte string:

```
import itertools
import struct


BINCODE = struct.Struct('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBb')


class State:
    __slots__ = '_bstring'
    TOP = 1
    BOTTOM = 0

    def __init__(self, seeds=4, *, top=None, bottom=None, turn=0):
        top = top if top else [seeds] * 6 + [0]
        bottom = bottom if bottom else [seeds] * 6 + [0]
        self._bstring = BINCODE.pack(*itertools.chain(bottom, top), turn)

    @property
    def top():
    ...
```

The idea was that the state._bstring, which is convieniently already packed as binary data could be turned nicely into a c struct similar to this:

```
struct State
{
    unsigned int bottom[7];
    unsigned int top[7];
    int turn;
}
```

which my C code could operate on, generate the resulting C State as new binary data and be slotted directly into a new python `State` object.

However I can't seem to find any information about how to go about this. Almost all the information I can find is about packing and unpacking C data from a file. 
I've considered using the `PyObject_GetBuffer` on the bytes object, but the game logic is pretty complex and I'd prefer to deal with the data as a struct rather than an array. Moreover I'd like to reduce the amount of copying to a minimum.

The other option I looked into was using a `PyCapsule` object defined in C as the new State for python, but I would lose all of the State classes python specific functionality. I'd really rather keep changes to the python code to an absolute minimum, as many of the previous python optimizations are dependent on the data format.

Cython doesn't seem to have a way to coerce binary data into a C struct pointer. And re-writing `State` to be numba compatible would lose crucial functionality like unique hashing etc.

It seems like there should be a fairly straight forward way to do this, but I can't seem to find it. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could also, use a list of `15` `int` (*after all there are no unsigned integers in python AFAIK*) items and interpret it in [tag:c] the way you need, or simple pass a pointer back and fort. Are you familiar with python extensions in [tag:c]?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I'm familiar with python extansions in c, though I wouldn't call myself an expert by any means. Could you point me to a resource that shows how to get a bytes pointer in python, pass it to c, cast it as a struct, pass it back and cast it back to t bytestring? I have a working solution that uses the bufferview in c but I have other situations with mixed types that can't be easily coerced into an array.

Comment: All python methods that you define in [tag:c] receive a pointer of type `PyObject` you can use like if it was a OO class, and "*extend it*".

Comment: Please take a look [at this file](https://github.com/iharob/apache-ws/blob/master/python/src/py-apache-ws.c), I wrote it. There you can see how to create a Python obejct in [tag:c], I think this will fit perfectly and let you achieve your goal. Sorry if it's not well commented, it's a hobby project and I promised to comment it later, but you know ...

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I'm familiar with the `PyObject` pointer for python objects, but it's not clear to me how I would use it to read my byte data as a C struct. Creating a new `State` object in C isn't what I want to do. If for example I had a python bytestring in the format `'clf?'` how could I read that in C as a `struct x{ char, long, float, bool}`?

Comment: I don't know, I don't think it will be ever useful for me to learn that because the way I say is really easy. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've worked out my solution, and it was fairly straight forward. I seem to have misunderstood the way `Py_buffer` worked.

The python `bytes` type implements the buffer protocol so you can use the `PyObject_GetBuffer` function to get a reference to the underlying data. The `buffer.buf` points to the data as a `void` pointer which can be freely cast to whatever structure you want.

Here's some (simplified) code:

```
#include <Python.h>

typedef struct State{
    char board[14];
    char turn;
} State;


static PyObject *py_after_move(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    PyObject *buffobj;
    Py_buffer view;
    int move;

    //get the passed PyObject
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Oi", &buffobj, &move)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    //get buffer info
    if (PyObject_GetBuffer(buffobj, &view, PyBUF_ANY_CONTIGUOUS | PyBUF_FORMAT) == -1) {
        return NULL;
    }

    //copy and cast as a state
    State state;
    memcpy(&state, view.buf, sizeof(state));
    for (int i=0; i < 14; i++) {
        state.board[i] += 1; /// example modifications
    }
    state.turn++;

    //re-cast as characters and place in new bytes object
    char *aschr = (char*) &state;
    PyBuffer_Release(&view);
    return Py_BuildValue("y#", aschr, sizeof(state));
}
/* python module boilerplate goes here */
```

Here I do a `memcpy` of the buffer since since I don't want to mutate the input.

#### Some Notes:

- be careful sizing your structs. The above code should really check that the `view.len == 15` and raise an error if it does not. Failure to do so can lead to seg-faults and security issues
- It's not considered kosher in **C99** to cast a pointer to or from anything that isn't a void. So in the above code the cast from `view.buf` to `State` is fine, since `view.buf` is of type `*void`. However the cast from state to char is not. Ideally this would be a void pointer.

#### References:

- [PyBuffer struct](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/buffer.html#buffer-structure)
- [PyBytes_FromObject](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/bytes.html#c.PyBytes_FromObject)

Comment: For future reference, not that if you had posted your code initially then help would have arrived much sooner. I had no idea what you was doing actually or how.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Yeah, that's my fault. I thought that since the `Py_GetBuffer` call got information about arrays, such as the item size and type it would only work for array like items with uniform type. I didn't realize that the underlying buffer pointer was a void type and gave you free access to the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You would ideally write a simple python module like the following,

```
#include <Python.h>

struct State {
    unsigned int bottom[7];
    unsigned int top[7];
    int turn;
};

struct PyState {
    PyObject_HEAD
    struct State *internal;
};

static void PyState_free(PyObject *self);

static PyMethodDef py_mygamestate_module_methods[] = {{NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}};
static struct PyModuleDef py_mygamestate_module = {
   PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
   /* name of module */
   "mygamestate",
   /* module documentation, may be NULL */
   NULL,
   /* size of per-interpreter state of the module, or -1
    * if the module keeps state in global variables.
    */
   -1,
   py_mygamestate_module_methods,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL
};

static PyObject *py_state_show(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);

static PyMethodDef py_state_methods[] = {
    {"show", py_state_show, METH_NOARGS, NULL},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static PyObject *py_state_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *parent, PyObject *args);

#define Py_BASE_TYPE_FLAGS (Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE)
static PyTypeObject py_state_type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "State",                   /* tp_name */
    sizeof(struct PyState),    /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                         /* tp_itemsize */
    PyState_free,              /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                         /* tp_print */
    0,                         /* tp_getattr */
    0,                         /* tp_setattr */
    0,                         /* tp_as_async */
    0,                         /* tp_repr */
    0,                         /* tp_as_number */
    0,                         /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                         /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                         /* tp_hash */
    0,                         /* tp_call */
    0,                         /* tp_str */
    0,                         /* tp_getattro */
    0,                         /* tp_setattro */
    0,                         /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_BASE_TYPE_FLAGS,        /* tp_flags */
    "Docstring",               /* tp_doc */
    0,                         /* tp_travers */
    0,                         /* tp_clear */
    0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                         /* tp_iter */
    0,                         /* tp_next */
    py_state_methods,          /* tp_methods */
    0,                         /* tp_members */
    0,                         /* tp_getset */
    &PyBaseObject_Type,        /* tp_base */
    0,                         /* tp_dict */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
    0,                         /* tp_init */
    0,                         /* tp_alloc */
    py_state_new,              /* tp_new */
    0,                         /* tp_free */
    0,                         /* tp_is_gc */
    0,                         /* tp_bases */
    0,                         /* tp_mro */
    0,                         /* tp_cache */
    0,                         /* tp_subclasses */
    0,                         /* tp_weaklist */
    0,                         /* tp_del */
    0,                         /* tp_version_tag */
    0                          /* tp_finalize */
};

static void
PyState_free(PyObject *self)
{
    free(((struct PyState *) self)->internal);
}

static PyObject *
py_state_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *parent, PyObject *args)
{
    struct PyState *state;
    PyObject *self;
    self = PyType_GenericNew(type, parent, args);
    if (self == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // Cast the object to the appropriate type
    state = (struct PyState *) self;
    // Initialize your internal structure
    state->internal = malloc(sizeof(*state->internal));
    if (state->internal == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memset(state->internal, 0, sizeof(*state->internal));
    // This means no error occurred
    return self;
}

static PyObject *
py_state_show(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    struct State *state;
    // Cast the object to the appropriate type
    state = ((struct PyState *) self)->internal;
    if (state == NULL)
        return NULL;
    fprintf(stdout, "bottom: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        fprintf(stdout, "%d, ", state->bottom[i]);
    fprintf(stdout, "top: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        fprintf(stdout, "%d, ", state->bottom[i]);
    fprintf(stdout, "turn: %d\n", state->turn);
    return self;
}

PyObject *
PyInit_mygamestate(void)
{
    PyObject *module;
    // Prepare the base classes to add them
    if (PyType_Ready(&py_state_type) < 0)
        return NULL;
    // Create the apache module
    module = PyModule_Create(&py_mygamestate_module);
    if (module == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // Add the base classes
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "State", (PyObject *) &py_state_type);
    return module;
}
```

note that the name of the module *dll* or *so* file should match the part after the underscore in `PyInit_mygamestate`.

Now if you install the *so* file to the *site-packages* directory, then from python you can do this

```
import mygamestate

state = mygamestate.State()
state.show()
```

That way you can have any type, as a python type and c type at the same time.

You can of course grow the `py_state_methods` array to the size you want, and have any methods that would be useful from within the python code. You can also pass parameters to the constructor and to each method, and so on.

There is another array, namely `py_mygamestate_module_methods` that will be methods accessible directly to the module in the python code.

**Note**: The orignal code was modified, so now it allows inheritance and you can do something like this

```
from mygamestate import State

class CustomState(State):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # add all your custom methods here
    def sample_method(self):
        print('Cool, it works')

state = CustomState()
state.show()
state.sample_method()
```

The changes were,

1. Add the `Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE` to the `tp_flags` member. This allows the type to be subclassable, but then the `tp_init` function is no longer used, and the initialization needs to be performed in `tp_new` instead — *I have no idea why it is like that, IMHO it's stupid* —.
2. Remove the `py_state_init` function and instead create a `py_state_new` function, replacing the `PyType_GenericNew` function for the `tp_new` member of the `PyTypeObject` instance that is our custom type.

   We call the original `PyType_GenericNew()` to create our type object and then, perform what the old `py_state_init()` did to initialize our internal structure data.

By inheriting from this class, you can have both things that you wish.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, and I may end up going this way. It's just that the current python `State` class is about 100 lines of fairly complicated python code with methods for hashing, item getting, class methods other decorators etc. so while the actual data is very simple and small. I don't much fancy re-creating  all the methods in c. Maybe I can find a way to make the c version a parent class of my python version. It just seems like so much complication for something that already has a simple, compact, and c friendly binary representation.

Comment: No, apparently you will need more to make the class an acceptable base class.

Comment: @Laharah Please check the updated answer, I think this now really fits your use case.

Comment: Thanks so much for typing this up. Did some testing with your version and it does indeed work well. However inheriting from the c version caused problems with some python optimizations (eg: `__slots__` for memory footprint). However, I did manage to figure out what I was trying to do originally. It turns out I misunderstood the way `PyObject_GetBuffer` worked. I typed up my answer below.

Comment: @Laharah I'm glad. I don't blame you, the documentation in fact sucks.